# De Rham cohomology of Lie groupoid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, derham-cohomology, lie-groupoids

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on a manifold $M$.

Consider the transformation groupoid $\mathcal{G}=(G\times M\rightrightarrows M)$.  We have the notion of de Rham cohomology of a Lie groupoid by considering de Rham cohomology of simplicial manifold associated to it, denoted by $\mathcal{G}_\bullet$.

Is there any relation between de Rham cohomology of Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ (eg page 11 of Laurent-Gengoux–Tu–Xu, *Chern-Weil map for principal bundles over groupoids*, Math. Z. **255** (2007) pp451–491, arXiv:[math/0401420](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401420v3)) and the de Rham (??) cohomology of the Lie group $G$ and the de Rham cohomology of the manifold $M$?

Comment: What is DeRham Cohomology of a Lie groupoid ? Do you mean groupoid cohomology defined the same way as group cohomology but restricting to composable chains ?

Comment: Please see edit @InfiniteLooper

Comment: In this special case your de Rham cohomology associated to the Lie groupoid is classically known as equivariant (Borel) cohomology.  There is a Serre spectral sequence that has the flavour of what you want and is often used to compute equivariant cohomology; see (1.2.1) of http://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/pdf/equivariant.jour.pdf. Note that first page of the Serre spectral sequence involves cohomology over $BG$, in general with twisted coefficient group. The relation to $H^*(G)$ is more subtle (this is the "Koszul duality" in the title of the linked paper).

Comment: @DanielPomerleano Thanks for the link. Can you give a reference for “Lie groupoid cohomology same thing as Equivariant cohomology”. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition $13$ and Remark $16$ in page $10$ of [Cohomology or Stacks](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/CohSta-1.pdf) says that, there is a natural isomorphism

$$H^i_G(X)\rightarrow H^i(X\times G\rightrightarrows X)$$
where, $H^i_G(X)$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ equivariant cohomology of $X$ with respect to action of $G$ and $H^i(X\times G\rightrightarrows X)$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ deRham cohomology of the transformation groupoid $(X\times G\rightrightarrows X)$.

Comment: The existence of such an isomorphism does not depend on $G$ compact, as stated in Remark 16 of the paper you link.

Comment: @MikeMiller edited. Thanks